# Can I do 3 external monitor instead of 2 external+1 internal on a Macbook Pro 13"?

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, macbook-pro, external-display

I know I can run 2 external plus the internal monitor without any issues.

Since it won't let me add a third external (for a total of 4), I'd prefer just running the 3 external ones with a closed lid.

Is there a way to make this happen?

The MBP in question is a Mid-2015 retina with Intel Iris Graphics 6100.

Comment: To those who have no idea, MBP = Mac Book Pro.